# MS SQL Server sleeping transactions lock

Tags: java, sql-server, transactions, deadlock, rollback

I have a problem with `sleeping transaction locks on MS SQL Server 2008`.

Sometimes it's not really sleeping or when transaction is not completed and there is real lock. But this is not my case.

We have **tomcat 6** and **java app** on it. When I'm doing any update in java and then I'm trying to select updated records - no luck.

If I use with (nolock) - it helps, I see the correct changed rows, but then, after some period of time this updated is rolled back.
If I do update through `Studio` - then it works fine, immediate result.

Similar situation I have in many places of my application.
For example I have nightly job which is doing recalculation of big chunks of data into **bitfields**. And at the end it removes old bitfields and copies new **bitfields** inside. But when job is completed - rollback happens. I tried to save these bitfields manually in tmp tables and then I replaced old with new one through Studio - it worked.

All statements and connections are closed. I verified. And I tried to do all these changes in scope of one transaction.
This application was running for a long period of time without any troubles, but now something happened.

I tried to find out the reason and used **sp_who**, **sp_who2**, different scripts which shows locking queries, also I did massive monitoring with SQL server profiler and I tried to find any solution on the Internet. I found only
 `Error: 1222, Severity: 16, State: 18` 
which is the result of this problem, not the cause. May be I'm moving in wrong direction. For me it looks like something changed in SQL server configuration and now, for some reason, it holds connection and all changes, which were made in scope of it for ever. When this connection is killed - everything rolled back.

If you have any ideas I would appreciate it.
Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE:** I've searched and found one article:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/137983
and there is an option like: 
If the Windows NT Server computer has successfully closed the connection, but the client process still exists on the SQL Server as indicated by sp_who, then it may indicate a problem with SQL Server's connection management. In this case, you should work with your primary support provider to resolve this issue.
May be this is mine option. I will investigate it further.

Comment: you can try this solution, i hope you find here what you need [dba stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10912/sql-server-transaction-timeout/10929#10929)

Comment: Are you using a connection pool? Maybe you are using an implementation that doesn't rollback open transactions when a connection is returned to the pool?

Comment: @ahmed, Sorry but that one didn't help. It just reduced rollback time.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I'm just using simple JDBC connection to the database. The problem is that at the end everything is rollbacked.

Comment: If you don't use auto commit, and you don't explicitly commit, then a driver will rollback on connection close.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I got your point Mark. But I use auto commit. I also tried to do explicit commit on connection which should release all locks but this didn't help. When server was stopped  - all changes were rolled back.